# Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'guild' is not defined discord.py

Tags: python, discord

error:

```
Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'guild' is not defined
```

code:

```
@bot.command()
async def servers(ctx):
servers=list(bot.guilds)
embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Server list, {guild.members}  members',description='\n'.join(server.name for server in servers))
await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```

idk but this command works 10 mins ago

Comment: Is this the whole code? If so, guild is, in fact, not defined. Apart from that, your code isn't indented which would cause another error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the context parameter all of your guilds should have ctx.guild read the documents and indent your code even if you fix it without indents it will not work python is very serious with indenting

Fixed Code

```
@bot.command()
async def servers(ctx):
    servers=list(bot.ctx.guilds)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Server list, {ctx.guild.members} members',description='\n'.join(server.name for server in servers))
    await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```